# Disable babel's shorthands

Tags: babel, preamble, shorthands

I want to disable babel's shorthands in my own sty file.

But since I can use `\shorthands{off}` only inside the document environment, I struggle with this.

Is there a way to disable babel's shorthands in the preamble already?

Comment: the shorthands are already not active in the preamble. They are activated by babel with `\AtBeginDocument{...}`

Comment: I know that they're not active in the preamble. I want to disable them in the preamble so that they are inactive in the document environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\let\LanguageShortHands\languageshorthands
\def\languageshorthands#1{}
\begin{document}

"`foo"'

\LanguageShortHands{ngerman}
"`foo"'
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the babel.sty the shorthands are loaded if
    \pdfstringdefDisableCommands
is not defined.
Is it another way to define it to switch off shorthands initially?

Comment: that is related to `hyperref`

Answer (score 13):

Babel 3.9 now provides a package option to deactive shorthands at once:

```
\usepackage[shorthands=off,ngerman]{babel}
```

Their functionality are still available with `\babelshorthand`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a beta package [`babeltools`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bezos/babeltools.pdf), to be loaded before `babel`, that plans to allow this, with the addition of selectively enabling some shorthands.

Comment: Useful hint, but there is no »babel only way« for this?

Comment: Others have looked at a babel-only way in the past without complete success (e.g. [http://uucode.com/blog/2005/10/04/avoiding-babel-shorthands/](http://uucode.com/blog/2005/10/04/avoiding-babel-shorthands/), coming from a CTT discussion [http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/5fbd187d7807fd3d/6456d8adaa925a94?pli=1](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/5fbd187d7807fd3d/6456d8adaa925a94?pli=1)) but I don't know if that has been looked at more recently. Given the recent writing of `babeltools` and its inclusion in TeX Live, perhaps not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use `PassOptionsToPackage` before `documentclass` like this:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{shorthands=off}{babel}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}

"`foo"'

\LanguageShortHands{ngerman}
"`foo"'
\end{document}
```