# Multilingual document: Problem between babel and csquotes: \MakeOuterQuote{"}

Tags: punctuation, babel, csquotes, german

[image: Example]: Line 5 is my problem...

I want to use simple quotation marks in a multilingual document with `csquotes` AND `babel`, with the help of `\MakeOuterQuote{"}`, and I need the command `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` to return to German. (Line 2 and 3 show a solution with the environment `otherlanguage*` which I cannot use).

It seems that `babel` overwrites the OuterQuote of `csquotes`. Anybody an idea?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[french,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[babel,german=quotes,french=quotes]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}

"abend", "beispiel" (\languagename) 

\begin{otherlanguage*}{french}
"abend", "beispiel" (\languagename) 
\end{otherlanguage*}

"abend", "beispiel" (\languagename)

\selectlanguage{french} 
"abend", "beispiel" (\languagename) 

\selectlanguage{ngerman} 
"abend", "beispiel" (\languagename) 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With the `ngerman` option activated, `"` becomes a shorthand prefix, and this interferes with your usage for quotes, because `"a` is used to type “ä”, for instance, and this has precedence. So `"a` produces ä but `"b` goes well, because it's not a defined shorthand.

Comment: That's right, thank you, but the first and the third line are in `ngerman` option as well, with the wanted behaviour of `csquotes`.

Comment: crossposting http://www.golatex.de/mehrsprachiges-dokument-problem-zw-babel-und-csquotes-t12267.html

Comment: I recommend using `\enquote`, or at least `»` and `«` to specify the outer delimiters.

Comment: @user43669 Your setting of `\MakeOuterQuote{"}` initially overrides the `ngerman` ones, but an explicit `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` restores the default of `babel`.

Comment: And of course if the hack linked to by Ulrike is unappealing, you can still do "`abend"', which doesn't seem that much more onerous.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I should have mentioned the crossposting, thank you for your solution! I will try all these answers, thanks. But I think, Ulrike's hack is what I need. The problem is that i have to `include` different texts from other authors. `»` and `«` is even the contrary for french and german writers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to make your hack, with an according warning, into an answer and get this off the list?

Answer (score 4):

I'm only answering to get the question from the "unanswered queue". Personally I don't think that it is a good idea to overload ascii chars like this. There are too much potential places (e.g. the bib-file) where the char needs to have the "other" meaning. I myself use `\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}` together with a sensible shortcut in my editor to put the quotes around selected text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[french,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[babel,german=quotes,french=quotes]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
\let\mycsouterquote"
\addto\extrasngerman{\let"\mycsouterquote}
\addto\extrasfrench {\let"\mycsouterquote}

"abend", "beispiel" (\languagename)

\begin{otherlanguage*}{french}
"abend", "beispiel" (\languagename)
\end{otherlanguage*}

"abend", "beispiel" (\languagename)

\selectlanguage{french}
"abend", "beispiel" (\languagename)

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
"abend", "beispiel" (\languagename)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used this to solve the issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451173/67787

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with this problem myself, I decided to simply [disable shorthands globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106325/84994). My texts are generally UTF-8 encoded so that Umlauts et al are printed just fine.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[shorthands=off, % Don't translate quotation marks followed by vocals to umlauts
            ngerman         % Neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```