angle using pgfPlot
This does not work.
Why does \loesung block the \usetikzlibrary{babel}?
\loesung works well wiht pgfplots, but not here.
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%%%% NOT RELATED, BUT ADDED
\usetikzlibrary{babel}%%%% ADDED, SOLVES BABEL-QUOTES CLASH
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%for ifthen
\newtoggle{showComments} %switch to show or hide  \loesung

\newcommand{\loesung}[1]{
    \iftoggle{showComments}
    {\textbf{Lösung: }#1}
    {}
}

\toggletrue{showComments} 
%\togglefalse{showComments}

\begin{document}
    \loesung{
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (HP) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (5,5);
        % Winkel
        \draw pic [draw=orange, "$\beta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--B--HP};
    \end{tikzpicture}
 }
    
\end{document}


(BTW: I read the related questions and did search for that babel issue (fixed it 4 Month ago), but could not find :
\usetikzlibrary{babel})
I really prefer not having any warnings, but i am not able to.
Thanks
Patrick

Please can you edit your question with a full minimal complete code starting from \documentclass?

Try first  withbabel and tikz only. Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166772/316068.

Seems the classical babel shorthand/tikz clash. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28522/disable-babels-shorthands (but it's impossible to say without a compilable example. You can make one by bisecting your preamble...)

@Rmano Are you like a cristal ball?

@Sebastiano I have one:

This causes the bug, it helps me to switch the document with or without "Lösung".
 \iftoggle{showComments}
 {\textbf{Lösung: }#1}
 {}
}```

Correct crystal ball ;-). This is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw. Add (better immediately after loading pgfplots) \usetikzlibrary{babel} and your example compiles correctly.

@Patrick, I can't really understand what the "loesung" thing has to do with the question --- please, one question per question on this site.

Moreover, you have a typo; you wrote \shothandon (look closely), which is why it doesn't work. Anyway, loading the babel library is the good solution in this case.

With this \loesung \usetikslibrary{babel} does not work. This is the question, i solved  the babel ting 4 month ago without \loesung, now it did not wordk and i did not know why. I now know it is the \loesung thing, but do not know how to solve.

@Patrick: please DON'T DO THAT: changing a question after it has an answer invalidate a) the answer b) the work the answerer dedicated to it c) the usefulness of the Q&A to other users. Read how this site works and ask a different question!

But this was my question from the beginning. Angle and pic did not work!
And \shorthandoff and \shorthandon neither. i did not know, it is the \loesung thing.
OK, i make a new question.

You have the answer here, for this time there is no need to add a new question. But please try to remember this for the next time!

Answer to the original question, before the OP changed it:
Although this question will probably be closed because it is a duplicate of "when having Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra } try to add \usetikzlibrary{babel}", let me add an answer to help in a couple of things...
The OP should:

try to do a real minimum example. In this case, this one suffices:

%! TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]
    \coordinate (HP) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (5,5);
    \draw pic [draw=orange, "$\beta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--B--HP};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


check for trivial errors, like the \shothandon syntax error (LaTeX tells you that quite clearly), and try to avoid warnings in your MWE

Ask just one question per question, and possibly put everything in English...


Anyway, the solution here is:
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%%%% NOT RELATED, BUT ADDED
\usetikzlibrary{babel}%%%% ADDED, SOLVES BABEL-QUOTES CLASH
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (HP) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (5,5);
    % Winkel
    \draw pic [draw=orange, "$\beta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--B--HP};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

which compiles correctly (as well as your example, minus the typo). Using \shorthandoff/on can work, but it's dangerous because the problem is a catcode one, so the timing is very important(*).
BTW --- no need to use the dimensions on every coordinate (TiKZ defaults to x=y=1cm), and scale=1, transform shape is clearly a no-op here (although a probably quite expensive one).

(*) "the timing," in this case, means when TeX reads and converts the tokens. For example, it is normal that a diagram with \shorthandoff/on works when used directly in the code but stops working when used in a macro argument, which I think is what you mean with the "lösung" thing (I do not know what that means, sorry...)
Update after the OP changed the question
...and this is why your (edited, grrrr) new question do not work. You have to use \usepackage[ngerman, shorthand=off]{babel}. I do not think it's possible at all to have babel shorthands and full TikZ special char support at the same time (but given that you can use UTF-8 now, they're rarely needed...)
Moreover, standalone with tikz is thought to produce just one tikzpicture (so your example compile in two pages here). Try
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman, shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%%%% NOT RELATED, BUT ADDED
\usetikzlibrary{babel}%%%% ADDED, SOLVES BABEL-QUOTES CLASH
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%for ifthen
\newtoggle{showComments} %switch to show or hide  \loesung

\newcommand{\loesung}[1]{
    \iftoggle{showComments}
    {\textbf{Lösung: }#1}
    {}
}

\toggletrue{showComments}
%\togglefalse{showComments}

\begin{document}
    \loesung{

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (HP) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (5,5);
        % Winkel
        \draw pic [draw=orange, "$\beta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--B--HP};
    \end{tikzpicture}
 }

\end{document}



Thanks a lot, but does not work with \loesung

Please post a different question with a different minimal example. Anyway, that could be a catcode thing too. Try loading babel with \usepackage[ngerman, shothands=off]{babel}

@Patrick: please DON'T DO THAT: changing a question after it has an answer invalidate a) the answer b) the work the answerer dedicated to it c) the usefulness of the Q&A to other users. Read how this site works and ask a different question!

Is "baby shorthands" intentional or a typo? It would be a funny name for babel shorthands!

I was told to edit it and not to make comments or answers, sorry
\usepackage[ngerman, shorthands=off]{babel} does compile, but now in the document there is no pgfplot., Only "Lösung" nothing else. Should this question be removed?

You edit the question to explain more, if you have another question you ask another question... I have your plot (it's a TikZ picture, not a pgfplot). It just goes on the second page because you are using standalone with arguments that force just one paragraph. Wait a moment and I update the answer. Do not delete it.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that was the autocorrect... But yes, it sounded nice.
